# I need to assign a value to textbox where the value will be the value of the currently pressed button

Tags: javascript

I need to assign a value to textbox where the value will be the value of the currently pressed button..i have used the following codes

```
<button id="but0" value="0" onClick="button_value(this.id)">0</button>

function button_value(id)
{
    var val=document.getElementById(id).value  ;
  alert(val) ;
//display.value=val;
}
```

but i couldnot achieve the output...can anyone help me out

Comment: It works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/WYVsz/

Comment: Don't pass the ID, pass `this` so the function can just do `var val = this.value`.

Comment: So what's the problem/error?  It works for me in jsfiddle, too.  I checked Firefox, Chrome, and IE.

Comment: that alert is working but nothing is getting printed in the textbox

Comment: display is the name of the textbox i gave

Comment: am getting alert no problem in that...but istead making it as an alert i need to assign that value to a textbox in the same form...can yo help me out

Comment: Please demonstrate an actual attempt before asking a question, we are not here to code for you.

Answer (score 0):

put this in your load event and change the apropriate IDs of your elements.

```
var button = document.getElementById("button");
var input = document.getElementById("input");

button.onclick=function(){
  input.value = document.getElementById("button").innerHTML;
};
```